# Mesh Deformation due to rigging

Tags: modeling, rigging

After I rigged a model part I noticed that some linked parts got *kinda* deformed, mostly they moved from the original position.

[image]

Does anyone knows what causes this and how can I prevent or fix that issue?
I tried to move the linked part but the whole mesh starts to follow it... Yeah,  I'm more of a 3DMax user and I'm kinda lost on Blender.

Comment: This is mostly due to wrong/inaccurate weithing of your skinning. we could give you more indepth answer if you provide us your blendfile. you can upload it here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Also, pls update the title of your question to a proper sentence that fits your problem. i recomend sth like "mesh gets deformed after adding a rig"

Comment: Try playing with weight paint . If this didn't work it would be way easier for us to give you a solution if you provide your .blend file .

Answer (score 1):

What's apparent in your image is deformation that differs between the talon and the toe.  The reason for this is that the margin of the talon has different weights than the margin of the toe.  If the vertices have the same weights, they will move together.

This is probably due to using automatic weights on a mesh with non-manifold boundaries-- ie, multiple separated meshes.  Autoweights are not a great way to weight these kinds of meshes.  You can merge the seams and then re-weight, or you can weight by hand, or you can create a manifold "cage" mesh, autoweight that, and then copy weights from it to your non-manifold meshes.

If your problem is that the rig isn't in its rest pose even when all bones have no transforms-- that as soon as you weight a model, it moves at all, even correctly-- then the issue is due to constraints or drivers that you've put on bones in your rig that cause them to transform, even when the bones haven't been transformed in pose mode.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Object mode, select the armature that you "have" in your current object (the one that doesn't deform well), then go to pose mode or edit mode and press <kbd>A</kbd> on your keyboard until all the bones are selected.

Then go to object mode, select the mesh object, go to weight paint. From there, in the menu, select Weights and then select "Assign Automatic from Bones".

Answer (score -1):

Even with the above answer distortion is inevitable, but fixable with the use of shape keys. I suggest researching these if working with realism in your animations.

Comment: Distortion is often avoidable with proper weight painting, especially in a case like this. Shape keys should not be necessary. This is almost definitely a case of incorrect weights, and trying to fix a weighting issue with shape keys is not a good idea.